# Why do we need to source setup.bash once in each terminal while running rosnode?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is its purpose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351829/why-do-we-need-to-source-setup.bash-once-in-each-terminal-while-running-rosnode?/) by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-08**:
This is a duplicate of at least #q251292, #q188309, #q250823, #q241528, #q269784, #q124131, #q292566 and #q229365. And #q286466 contains even more links to other Q&As which explain this.

It's really nice that @stevemacenski wrote yet another answer, but @Bobby: please try to search for existing Q&As before posting new ones.

Use Google: add `site:answers.ros.org` to your search query. It should turn up many relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To put it simply: your computer needs to know where to find the programs to run and where ROS is. This is setting up your terminal’s environment to know where to find the ROS commands and your software packages in the workspace.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-10**:
Thank you!